# TP-Link adapter TP-WN823N needs a lower kernel version - how can I downgrade?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, kernel, downgrade

I have brought a TP-Link adapter TP-WN823N which works fine on Windows & Mac but they didn't provide drivers for Linux. I found drivers for Linux but it is compatible only with Linux kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.10.10.

The problem is I am using latest version of Ubuntu (with kernel 4.4*) so to compile that driver I need a kernel version between 2.6.18 and 3.10.10.

I don't have internet access because of the driver issue, so is there any solution to this offline? I can boot my Windows (this is a dual boot system) to download files needed. How can I configure the adapter without downgrading the kernel if possible? Or how can I downgrade the kernel to compile the driver?

Comment: Can you update the question with info [from here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

Comment: I have a TPLink Card in my Gentoo Box that runs perfect using the `ath9k` driver, but before we can confirm that is the driver you need please do what @mikewhatever suggested as we need more information.